# Azure function get json from site and just pass it trough

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to pass data from link A to azure functions which just needs to get the data from link A and return that data on it's own.

So I get Json data from `A`, that data is served by an API. Now, I have a azure function and I need to grab the data from `A` and return `req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK)`, with the data from `A`. That needs to be visible (exactly the same) on `B` and `B` here is my Azure url...

How can  do this?

I tried to do a `await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`, but that doesn't do a thing..

So, my function app looks like this now:

```
[FunctionName("CreateRadioAPI")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CreateRadioAPIAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "v1/radio/stats/info")]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            try
            {
                //dynamic body = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("An error occured: ", ex);
                return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }
        }
```

In here, I want to return the data from the other link which looks like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "listeners": 65,
        "song": "Ofenbach - Katchi (Ofenbach vs. Nick Waterhouse)",
        "live_dj": ".-RRxd-.",
        "mini_rooster": [],
        "song_history": [
            {
                "playedat": 1512154754,
                "title": "Ofenbach - Katchi (Ofenbach vs. Nick Waterhouse)",
                "metadata": {
                    "tit2": "Ofenbach - Katchi (Ofenbach vs. Nick Waterhouse)"
                }
            },
            {
                "playedat": 1512154548,
                "title": "Cam'ron - Hey Ma",
                "metadata": {
                    "tit2": "Cam'ron - Hey Ma"
                }
            },
            {
                "playedat": 1512154335,
                "title": "San Holo - I Still See Your Face",
                "metadata": {
                    "tit2": "San Holo - I Still See Your Face"
                }
            },
            {
                "playedat": 1512151761,
                "title": "Sunnieday Mixtape Dyna (5)",
                "metadata": {
                    "tit2": "Sunnieday Mixtape Dyna (5)"
                }
            },
            {
                "playedat": 1512151162,
                "title": "Merk & Kremont - Sad Story (Out Of Luck)",
                "metadata": {
                    "tit2": "Merk & Kremont - Sad Story (Out Of Luck)"
                }
            },
            {
                "playedat": 1512150866,
                "title": "Martin Garrix - So Far Away",
                "metadata": {
                    "tit2": "Martin Garrix - So Far Away"
                }
            },
            {
                "playedat": 1512150701,
                "title": "John de Sohn - Hum With Me",
                "metadata": {
                    "tit2": "John de Sohn - Hum With Me"
                }
            },
            {
                "playedat": 1512150345,
                "title": "Zak Abel - All I Ever Do (Is Say Goodbye)",
                "metadata": {
                    "tit2": "Zak Abel - All I Ever Do (Is Say Goodbye)"
                }
            },
            {
                "playedat": 1512150139,
                "title": "Dua Lipa - New rules",
                "metadata": {
                    "tit2": "Dua Lipa - New rules"
                }
            },
            {
                "playedat": 1512149995,
                "title": "Garmiani - Fogo",
                "metadata": {
                    "tit2": "Garmiani - Fogo"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of random lines of code.

Comment: I've updated the codes

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want something like this:

```
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

[FunctionName("CreateRadioAPI")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CreateRadioAPIAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "v1/radio/stats/info")]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    try
    {
        var responseFromA = await client.GetAsync("https://yoursite.com/a.json");
        var body = await responseFromA.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error("An error occured: ", ex);
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

Comment: Jep, that was what I needed, except I have a cloudflare issue (captcha), which can't be fixed I guess ( I have no access to cloudflare)...